# IBM Eclipse WSDL Editor: How do I include an external wsdl/schema?

Tags: eclipse, import, wsdl, include, topdown

I am trying to create Web Services from the Top-Down approach. I downloaded Eclipse and am using the WSDL gui editor in it to build my WSDL files.

I am splitting up my Services based on "modules". The Types I am adding to the WSDLs all need to reference common stuff, such as PersonEntity, AddressEntity, States enumeration (simple type), Countries enumeration (simple type), and AbstractEntity. Since those items are all common I created a seperate WSDL file (named Commons.wsdl) that contains the type information for those types.

I want to "import" that WSDL into my other WSDL files to use:

For example, I have an entity named RegistrationEntity which inherits from AbstractEntity and contains a PersonEntity as well as an AddressEntity. I'm not sure how to do this... I saw that the WSDL spec has "import" and "include" and am not sure which one to use. Also, how do I actually import (or include) the Commons.wsdl file so that I can use the Types defined within it?

Thanks!

Oh, and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to stick this stuff in a seperate WSDL but another type of file such as an xsd or something. I really wanna follow best practices so if that's the proper way to do it then I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem I had was I was creating a WSDL file for my commons and using an inline scheme for that, rather than creating an XSD file to be imported by my other WSDLs.

So instead I just created an Commons.XSD as my "Common Schema".